# What's a good alternative to Romer's Advanced Macroeconomics?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

I am not liking Romer's Advanced Macroeconomics. I feel like it demands a stronger intuitive knowledge of economics than I currently possess, and on the other hand, it is not as theoretically strong and deep.

While I am trying to increase my intuition ... is there an alternative that covers roughly the same as Romer's book, but actually goes in-depth with all of the issues at a deep theoretical level, rather than just treat it intuitvely?

Answer (score 3):

I like [Introducing Advanced Macroeconomics: Growth and Business Cycles](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introducing-Advanced-Macroeconomics-Education-Economics/dp/0077117867) by Sorensen and Whitta-Jacobsen. The text provides intuitive explanation and exposition of models. The book is neither too mathy nor descriptive, I would say, they offer somewhat balanced introduction.

A similar question was submitted before, have a look [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/textbook-for-macroeconomics-advanced-undergrad?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Macroeconomics book is "Macroeconomics" from Rudiger Dornbusch, Stanley Fischer. You can find older edition for a good price. The theory is explained very well, and is good choice for Intermediate Macroeconomics class.

ISBN-10:
0078021839
ISBN-13:
9780078021831