# Macroeconomics textbook suggestion

Tags: reference-request, books

I'm looking for a book to refresh my macroeconomics and also continue studying the topics that I did not have. My math background is solid. Can anyone suggest a macro book that takes it from the beginning to advanced and covers hopefully most macroeconomics? if there is no such a book and a few books should be read, please also let me know your suggestions.

Comment: some of the suggestions [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/textbook-for-macroeconomics-advanced-undergrad) might be relevant to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Obstfeld and Rogoff (Foundations of International Macroeconomics) or Romer (Advanced Macroeconomics) both cover a lot and present all the math.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free introductory textbook, Caltech professor Preston McAfee's *Introduction to Economic Analysis* is available here: http://www.muhlenberg.edu/media/contentassets/pdf/economicanalysis/IEA.pdf and here: http://www.muhlenberg.edu/media/contentassets/pdf/economicanalysis/IEA.pdf

You can read more about the textbook here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Economic_Analysis