# Macroeconomics textbooks

Tags: macroeconomics

I want a book that has mathematical rigour as well as good explanations for an average student. It is for my master degree. So, something which is not too boring.

Comment: Recursive Macroeconomic Theory, Ljungqvist and Sargent! Great book, super complex and super helpful if you want to do DSGEs / Heterogenous agents models!

So, this is really if you want to do a PhD.

Otherwise, the Romer! Advanced Macroeconomics by David Romer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbook for macroeconomics (advanced undergrad)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/textbook-for-macroeconomics-advanced-undergrad)